# split[5] = "00" when it should be "0"

Tags: swift, split

I have a tableView method that allows the user to edit a row entry. However, when I edit the row entry a second time I get an index out of range error.

As you can see in line 679 (from image link), there is a fatal error caused by an out of range index. When I hold the cursor over the 'split' keyword, xCode says there are 7 values (0-6). However I know there should be 8, because if you look at the debug window and count the strings between the 2 colons delimiter you'll get 8 values (0-7).

If I hold the cursor over line 676 (from image link), split[5], it seems there are two numbers (double zero) in the string value, when there should always be only one digit. One of the double zero's should be in split[6], and split[6] currently has what should be split[7]'s value. Split[7] has no value assigned when it should have the name of the language string, and hence is out of index range.

I added lines 671-672, in case it helped but made no difference.

```swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
        let delete = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") {
            (action, sourceView, completionHandler) in
            if let defaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.co.uk.tirnaelectronics.hyperpolyglot.todayview") {
                if var savedWords = defaults.object(forKey: "words") as? [String] {
                    var savedWordIndex = 0
                    for savedWord in savedWords {
                        if savedWord.contains(self.tableViewWords[indexPath.row]) {
                            savedWords.remove(at: savedWordIndex)
                        }
                        savedWordIndex += 1
                    }
                self.words.removeAll()
                self.words = savedWords
                self.saveWords()
                }
            }
            self.tableViewWords.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tableView.beginUpdates()
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .left)
            tableView.endUpdates()
            // delete item at indexPath

            self.resetEnableDisable()
            self.chosenLanguageLoad()
            self.clearEnableDisable()
            self.chosenLanguageLoad()
            self.sortEnableDisable()
            completionHandler(true)
        }

        let edit = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "Edit") {
            (action, sourceView, completionHandler) in
            let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Edit word", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)

            // add two text fields, one for English and one for foreign word
            ac.addTextField { textField in
                let tableViewWord = self.tableViewWords[indexPath.row]
                let split = tableViewWord.components(separatedBy: "::")
                let englishWord = split[0]
                textField.placeholder = "\(englishWord)"
            }

            ac.addTextField { (textField) in
                let tableViewWord = self.tableViewWords[indexPath.row]
                let split = tableViewWord.components(separatedBy: "::")
                let foreignWord = split[1]
                textField.placeholder = "\(foreignWord)"
            }

            // create an "Edit Word" button that submits the user's input
            let submitAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Edit Word", style: .default) { [unowned self, ac] (action: UIAlertAction!) in
                // pull out the English and foreign words, or an empty string if there was a problem
                let firstWord = ac.textFields?[0].text?.capitalized ?? ""
                let secondWord = ac.textFields?[1].text?.capitalized ?? ""

                guard firstWord.count > 0 && secondWord.count > 0 else { return }
                // edit item at indexPath
                let split = self.tableViewWords[indexPath.row].components(separatedBy: "::")
                _ = split[0]
                _ = split[1]
                let wrongCount = split[2]
                let homeworkWrongCount = split[3]
                let attemptCount = split[4]
                let homeworkAttemptCount = split[5]
                let homeworkSet = split[6]
                // Line 677: Thread 1: Fatal Error: Index out of range when an edited word is re-edited.
                let language = split[7]

                self.editDefaultsKey(englishWord: firstWord, foreignWord: secondWord, wrongCount: wrongCount, homeworkWrongCount: homeworkWrongCount, attemptCount: attemptCount, homeworkAttemptCount: homeworkAttemptCount, homeworkSet: homeworkSet, language: language, index: indexPath.row)

                self.tableViewWords.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            self.tableViewWords.insert("\(firstWord)::\(secondWord)::\(wrongCount)::\(homeworkWrongCount)::\(attemptCount)::\(homeworkAttemptCount)\(homeworkSet)::\(language)", at: indexPath.row)

                tableView.beginUpdates()
                tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
                tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
                tableView.endUpdates()

                self.chosenLanguageLoad()
                self.resetEnableDisable()
                self.clearEnableDisable()
                self.sortEnableDisable()
            }

            // add the submit action, plus a cancel button
            ac.addAction(submitAction)
            ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel))

            // present the alert controller to the user
            self.present(ac, animated: true)
            completionHandler(true)
        }

        let homework = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "Homework") {
            (action, sourceView, completionHandler) in
            let tableViewWord = self.tableViewWords[indexPath.row]
            print("words in tableView editActionsForRowAt in WordsViewController are: \(self.words)")

            let split = tableViewWord.components(separatedBy: "::")
            if split[6] == "0" {
                let firstWord = split[0]
                let secondWord = split[1]
                let wrongCount = split[2]
                let homeworkWrongCount = split[3]
                let attemptCount = split[4]
                let homeworkAttemptCount = split[5]
                let homeworkSet = "1"
                let language = split[7]

                self.editDefaultsKey(englishWord: firstWord, foreignWord: secondWord, wrongCount: wrongCount, homeworkWrongCount: homeworkWrongCount, attemptCount: attemptCount, homeworkAttemptCount: homeworkAttemptCount, homeworkSet: homeworkSet, language: language, index: indexPath.row)

                self.tableViewWords.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            self.tableViewWords.insert("\(firstWord)"+"::"+"\(secondWord)"+"::"+"\(wrongCount)"+"::"+"\(homeworkWrongCount)"+"::"+"\(attemptCount)"+"::"+"\(homeworkAttemptCount)"+"::"+"\(homeworkSet)"+"::"+"\(language)", at: indexPath.row)
                print("Homework set button tapped")
            } else {
                let firstWord = split[0]
                let secondWord = split[1]
                let wrongCount = split[2]
                let homeworkWrongCount = split[3]
                let attemptCount = split[4]
                let homeworkAttemptCount = split[5]
                let homeworkSet = "0"
                let language = split[7]

                self.editDefaultsKey(englishWord: firstWord, foreignWord: secondWord, wrongCount: wrongCount, homeworkWrongCount: homeworkWrongCount, attemptCount: attemptCount, homeworkAttemptCount: homeworkAttemptCount, homeworkSet: homeworkSet, language: language, index: indexPath.row)

                self.tableViewWords.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            self.tableViewWords.insert("\(firstWord)"+"::"+"\(secondWord)"+"::"+"\(wrongCount)"+"::"+"\(homeworkWrongCount)"+"::"+"\(attemptCount)"+"::"+"\(homeworkAttemptCount)"+"::"+"\(homeworkSet)"+"::"+"\(language)", at: indexPath.row)
                print("Homework unset button tapped")
            }
            completionHandler(true)
        }

        delete.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemRed
        edit.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemBlue
        homework.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemGreen

        let swipeConfiguration = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [delete, edit, homework])

        return swipeConfiguration
    }
```

I expect:  `split[0] = "firstWord"`
           `split[1] = "secondWord"`
           `split[2] = "0"`
           `split[3] = "0"`
           `split[4] = "0"`
           `split[5] = "0"`
           `split[6] = "0"`
           `split[7] = "italian"`
But I get: `split[0] = "firstWord"`
           `split[1] = "secondWord"`
           `split[2] = "0"`
           `split[3] = "0"`
           `split[4] = "0"`
           `split[5] = "00"`
           `split[6] = "italian"`
           `split[7] = no value (Thread 1: fatal error: index out of range)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears it is just a parse issue with a missing `::` . Try replacing this:

```
  self.tableViewWords.insert("\(firstWord)::\(secondWord)::\(wrongCount)::\(homeworkWrongCount)::\(attemptCount)::\(homeworkAttemptCount)\(homeworkSet)::\(language)", at: indexPath.row)
```

With this:

```
  self.tableViewWords.insert("\(firstWord)::\(secondWord)::\(wrongCount)::\(homeworkWrongCount)::\(attemptCount)::\(homeworkAttemptCount)::\(homeworkSet)::\(language)", at: indexPath.row)
```

Comment: That was the problem, thx. Upvoted, but I don't have enough reputation to make it public. I always find it incredible how getting another pair of eyes on one's code can be quicker than staring blankly for hours by yourself!